# "Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected" error when declaring a method/function

Tags: c#

I'm going to apologize now, as I am super newby, and the answer to my question is probably sitting right in front of my face, but I just can't quite see where I'm going wrong with this one.

It's also worth mentioning, I also get a "} expected" error. Both errors are marked by location in my codeblock. :)

```
namespace AddingNumbers
{  //<---------------------- "} expected" error here.
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            public int AddNumbers(int number1, int number2)
            {
                int result = number1 + number2;
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
} //<--------- "Type or namespace definition, or end of file expected" error.
```

I'm writing this code with the help of a tutorial, and this is exactly the code that is shown in the tutorial, and in fact even if I copy in the code in the tutorial, I still get the error message...

Comment: You've placed the `AddNumbers` function _inside_ of the `Main` method.

Comment: If any of the provided answers solved your issue for you, please [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Accepting the answer that you found to be most helpful in solving your issue will mark this question as answered and help out the user whose answer you accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring a method (`AddNumbers`) *inside* of another method (`Main`). I think that what you are trying to do is this:

```
namespace AddingNumbers
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Do amazing stuff and eventually call AddNumbers from in here
        }

        public int AddNumbers(int number1, int number2)
        {
            int result = number1 + number2;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```